# Using tck = interpolate.bisplrep(x, y, z, kx=kx, ky=ky) to obtain z-values using an array of x- and y-values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, cubic-spline

I am performing a cubic spline using the attached code and I am able to print a z-value for a given x- and y-value. How can I extended the code to use an array of values for x and y? I would like to save the outputted z-values as an array. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate

y = np.array(input_data['y'])
z = np.array(input_data['z'])
x = np.array(input_data['z'])

spline = interpolate.Rbf(x,y,z,function='thin_plate',smooth=5, episilon=5)

kx, ky = 3, 3 

tck = interpolate.bisplrep(x, y, z, kx=kx, ky=ky)

print(interpolate.bisplev(42, 2.06921949, tck))
"""
Edit: example data

"""

x_new = [42, 56, 89 , 313]
y_new = [2.06921949, 4.1590951, 3.85620473, 1.57373633]

tck = interpolate.bisplrep(x, y, z, kx=kx, ky=ky)

print(interpolate.bisplev(x_new, y_new, tck))
```

Comment: You can pass arrays to `interpolate.bisplev`, ie. `interpolate.bisplev(x, y, tck)`

Comment: Thank you. I did this and got the following error **print(interpolate.bisplev( new_x, new_y , tck))

  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py", line 1049, in bisplev
    raise ValueError("Invalid input data")

ValueError: Invalid input data** code snippet `new_x = np.array(data['x1')

new_y = np.array(data['y1']) print(interpolate.bisplev(new_x, new_y,tck))`

Comment: It really depends what your data is and data type.

Comment: I have edited the question to include example data.

Comment: In this case I got the same error from your data! However if you pass `y` as `sorted(y)` it executes fine. As `bisplev` evaluates the full grid from your `x_new` and `y_new` this shouldn't be a problem. This answer is also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082881/invalid-input-data-from-scipys-cublic-spline-interpolation-process-bad-resul